# python 3.6 and f strings with a twist

Tags: python

I am using python3.6 and f strings
I have a config file which contains a query string like this

```
query = f'select column_name from {table_name}'  <---Stored in a config file

import ConfigParser
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('queries.txt')
for table_name in ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']:
    query = parser.get(query)
    print(query)
```

i want the query variable to contain

```
select column_name from table1
select column_name from table2
select column_name from table3
```

Is this possible using f strings ?

How do i achieve this in an elegant way ?

Comment: You could have a look at [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values) of the `configparser` documentation.

Comment: Hmm Kendas interesting but i am not sure the config parser interpolation would help me as the interpolation text for me is the elements of the list

Comment: In that case, your main option would probably be `query = parser.get(query).format(table_name=table_name)`

Comment: Kendas Brilliant thanks you nailed it :) Thanks a ton